# Germany emission sticker (Umweltplakette) Violation

Tags: legal, germany, driving

I got a letter in the mail from the Hessian government which says

> **Sie nahmen trotz eines Verkehrsverbots zur Verminderung schädlicher Luft verunreinigungen (Zeichen 270.1, 270.2) mit einem Kraftfahrzeug am Verkehr teil.
>   § 41 Abs. 1 iVm Anlage 2, § 49 StVO; § 24 StVG; 153 BKa**

I think this is because of a missing emissions sticker. The letter does not include any amount of fine.

If I admit the violation, how much money do I have to pay?

EDIT: The document is following

> *Ihnen wird vorgeworfen, am .... um .... Uhr in .... als Halter des PKW .... folgende Ordnungswidrigkeit begangen zu haben:
>   Sie nahmen trotz eines Verkehrsverbots zur Verminderung schädlicher Luftverunreinigungen (Zeichen 270.1, 270.2) mit einem Kraftfahrzeug am Verkehr teil.
>   § 41 Abs. 1 iVm Anlage 2, § 49 StVO; § 24 StVG; 153 BKat
>   Zeuge: ...
>
> Nach § 55 des Gesetzes über Ordnungswidrigkeiten (OWiG) haben Sie Gelegenheit innerhalb einer Woche, zu dem Vorwurf online mit Ihren Zugangsdaten oder schriftlich mit dem beigefügten Fragebogen Stellung zu nehmen. Es steht Ihnen frei, zur Sache auszusagen. Sie sind aber in jedem Fall - auch wenn Sie die Ordnungswidrigkeit nicht begangen haben - verpflichtet, unrichtige oder unvollständige Angaben zu Ihrer Person zu berichtigen oder zu vervollständigen. Die Verletzung dieser Pflicht ist nach § 111 OWiG mit Geldbuße bedroht. Sofern Sie sich nicht zu dem Vorwurf äußern, kann ohne weitere Anhörung ein Bußgeldbescheid gegen Sie erlassen werden.
>   Falls Sie sich äußern, werde ich aufgrund Ihrer Angaben entscheiden, ob das Verfahren eingestellt oder ohne weitere Antwort ein Bußgeldbescheid erlassen wird.
>
> Nach § 25a Straßenverkehrsgesetz werden dem Halter eines Fahrzeuges oder seinem Beauftragten die Kosten des Verfahrens wegen eines Halt- oder Parkverstoßes auferlegt, wenn der Fahrzeugführer, der den Verstoß begangen hat, nicht vor Eintritt der Verfolgungsverjährung ermittelt werden kann oder seine Ermittlung einen unangemessenen Aufwand erfordern würde.
>
> Sollten Sie selbst das Fahrzeug nicht abgestellt haben, so teilen Sie mir bitte die Personalien (auch Geburtsdatum und -ort) und Anschrift der verantwortlichen Person online oder schriftlich mit.
>
> Falls Sie den Fahrzeugführer nicht benennen, wären weitere Ermittlungen unangemessen. Ihnen würden dann die Kosten des Verfahrens auferlegt. Zu dieser Kostenentscheidung höre ich Sie hiermit an.
>
> Eine Information zur Verarbeitung Ihrer personenbezogenen Daten gemäß § 51 des Hessischen Datenschutz- und Informationsfreiheitsgesetzes (HDSIG) finden Sie auf der letzten Seite dieses Schreibens.
>
> Im Auftrag
>   ...
>   *

Comment: The amount of the fine does not depend on wether you admit the violation or not.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I just wonder the amount of fine.

Comment: There should be some sentences in the letter telling you what they actually want of you. Perhaps you can copy that here as well? Indeed the text that you copied suggests that they complain about a missing emissions sticker.

Comment: The letter does not have any sentences that relates to pay. I edited the question with copying full document.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about travel but about a legal letter.

Comment: I thought that the travelers that pass or stay at Germany should consider to buy this sticker. I had a punisment about that rule. Anyway, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears as if the current fine is [80 Euros](https://www.anwalt.de/rechtstipps/teilnahme-am-verkehr-in-einer-umweltzone-ohne-plakette-verfahrenseinstellung-vor-dem-ag-bremen_124830.html) if you admit the violation. There is no fine in the form of collecting points on your driver's license or the like, not even for those with German driver's licenses.

EDIT: After the edit of your question, it appears as if they are trying to find out who was the driver of the car (who is the person to be fined). You appear to be the owner of car and hence their point of contact. They officially ask for your input.

They write that they are allowed to fine *you* (the owner) in case you don't tell them (A lawyer may be able to tell you if that is actually true). They also inform you that you have them correct their information about you in case it is incorrect. They give you the opportunity to tell that you gave your car to somebody else who made the mistake of driving into a zone of environmental protection. If you give them information, they will decide based on the information to forget about the issue or to proceed (which most likely means issuing a fine).

They also write that in case you don't answer, it would be inappropriate for them to continue finding out who had the car. In this case, they will charge you for the (administrative) cost incurred so far. This appears to contradict what they write earlier and a lawyer may be able to tell if that is actually true. I find the sentence "Zu dieser Kostenentscheidung höre ich Sie hiermit an." in that context quite surprising and it may encode something legalese.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is very strange. I think the best I should do is accepting the violence and wait the second mail. Probably the second mail will include the amount of fine.

Comment: You are misinterpreting fine nuances in the German text. They write, that if he does not respond to the allegations, they will issue him a fine. Further they write, that if he does not name the driver (which is technically not the same as not responding), no further investigations will be conducted and he (the vehicle owner) will be liable for the administrive costs of the proceedings. If that is possible or not, is actually the main subject of the first article you are linking to.

Comment: It is also important to consider that if a vehicle holder is notified about a violation conducted with the vehicle and fails to name the driver, the vehicle holder is usually ordered to keep a driver's log book in the future, so that any potential upcoming violations can be associated with the actual driver.

Comment: Thank you. I send my personal information. I will write If I punished with fine.